# What settings should be used in AVD to accurately simulate the Recon MOD Live?

Tags: android

I am attempting to start development for a custom app for the Recon MOD Live before I receive the actual device. What settings should I use to be able to run the sample app and have it look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To best simulate MOD Live, give the AVD a 100MB SD card, and a screen resolution of 428x240.

Also make sure that the UI is accessible via DPAD buttons and a back button.

That's about it. MOD Live specific APIs are not available to be simulated.